# HttpContext is not available - Calling Webservice asychronously

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services, asynchronous, delegates

I currently have a web application project that also includes web services within the same project. I currently have a requirement to call the web service asynchronously. Since, I haven't added the web service as a web reference within the same project, I tried to call the web service method using delegates and I see an exception "HttpContext is not available.   This class can only be used in the context of an ASP.NET request" when I tried to access the Application property in my web service method call.

```
Web Method in MyWebServices Class
Public Function ProcessRequest() As Boolean
  If Application(STRING_KEY) Is Nothing Then 'Exception happens here'
     Return True
  Else
     Return False
  End If
End Sub

.ASPX Codebehind File
Public Delegate Function ProcessRequestDelegate() As Integer

Protected Sub btnSender_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles sender.Click
  Dim del As ProcessRequestDelegate
  del = New ProcessRequestDelegate(AddressOf ProcessRequest)
  del.BeginInvoke(null, null)
End Sub

Protected Function ProcessRequest() As Boolean
    Dim services As MyWebService
    services = New MyWebService()
    Return services.ProcessRequest()
End Function
```

Is what I am trying to do here is the right way to invoke a web method asyncrohously?

Thanks,
Javid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the web service class should be accessed via Web Reference and the method ProcessRequest should be decorated with the WebMethod attribute.

if you are using the web service as a normal class in the same project or from another project as if it was a normal class library you are not going through the Web Server so the HttpContext.Current object is null.